# Sprites with background position and width percentage in responsive design

Tags: html, css, sprite

I am designing an app with CSS3/HTML5 with a responsive design.

For performance, I use sprites  instead of normal images. So, I use `background-image` and `background-position`. On entire app the aspect ratio is maintained.

In a width with pixels and `background-position` with percentage, the image shows nice. But in a width with percentage and `background-position`, the image looks bad sometimes (when sprite has more than two images).

The sprite size 102px x 918 px;

Each image in the sprite size 102px x 102px;

The cross red is the last image in the sprite when 9 images.

See bad background-position:
[image: bad background-position in 612px]

It's the same but with 637px shows nice:
[image: good background-position in 637px]

Anybody know how to fix it with CSS3?

**UPDATE:**
My problem is with a percentage in the width and background-position.

```
background-position: 0 100%; // Show the second image in the sprite.
background-position: 0 700%; // Show image 8 in the sprite but sometimes, in some width, the image showed is the image 8 and a little image 7.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with background-size: cover. The browser doesn't render a correct width and height. To fix it i use:

```
background-size: 100% 900%; // 100% to adjust to width and 900% is to mantain proportions in the height. (9 images of 102px in this case)
```

I tested in chrome 26.

Answer (score 0):

Percentage value are best suitable for mobile devices compared to fixed pixels. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285058/css-percentages-or-pixels) for better understanding of pixel vs percentage.

Comment: I don't understand you. I use percentage. My problem is with a percentage in the width and background-position. `background-position: 0 100%; // Show the second image in the sprite. background-position: 0 700%; // Show image 8 in the sprite but sometimes, in some width, the image showed is the image 8 and a little image 7.` Do you know how i fix it? Thanks! P.D: See the images in my post please.