# HTML. Make Website Fit Other Devices And Screens?

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, device

I recently got "done" with a website (http://calcultr.comxa.com/). It looks fine on my screen, but on my friends' screen it does not fit the screen. The same with my other devices. I have added this to the Head tag:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1">
```

I have heard many people saying "that will fix the problem", but it didn't. I don't even know what it means. Were they lying?
**How would I make my website fit any device and screens?**

Comment: Put the above code in your web page and it will work!

Answer (score 1):

Your website doesn't display properly on your friends computer because he/she has another resolution. That's the complicated part of front-end designing. You have designed your website for ONE resolution/device/screen, now you have to do it for the rest, or at least come up with a solution that works for most devices and screens.

These are the options you have:

1. Design using percentages in CSS so that your page will adapt to a percentage of the screen of the user.
   [CSS - Percentages or Pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285058/css-percentages-or-pixels)
2. Use media queries to adapt the pixel sizing according to the users;'
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned,

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

... was not added to the top of the source code. And if you are trying to make it responsive, you may wish to add css media queries.

For example,

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: blue;
        //whatever styling...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at bootstrap. It is really simple and you can make responsiveness to all devices just by adding some naming to your id's and classes :) Here's the [link](http://getbootstrap.com/), hope this helps!

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot! Gonna try it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using frame work like bootstrap, foundation, etc.. if you want cross browser compatibility for front end designs

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you just need this bit of code:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
```

Comment: The charset meta tag is useful to make sure that the characters in the page are shown properly in all browsers and languages.   I'm not sure why you would suggest omitting it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with bootstrap

```
<html>enter code here
<head>
<title>FORM PAGE</title>    
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body style="background: #eee">
    <div class="container p-2 mt-5" style="background: #fff">
       <div class="row mt-5 text-center">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-12">
           <form>
              <label>enter your name</label>
               <input type="text" placeholder="enter your name" id="name"><br><br>
               
               <label>enter your age</label>
               <input type="text" placeholder="enter your age" id="age"><br><br>
               
               <label>enter your phone number</label>
               <input type="text" placeholder="enter your phone" id="phone"><br><br>
               
               <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">insert</button>
            
            </form>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).