# When is it okay to use percents in css?

Tags: html, css

I've notice that there are two different methods of quantifying the layout in CSS, that is by percentage and pixels. I know that it depends on which one that is being used, it would  change the layout. Under which circumstance should one be used over another and is there a uniform standard if there is a preference?

Comment: There's also em, rem, ex, cm, mm, in, pt, pc, vh, vw, vmin, vmax, etc.. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285058/css-percentages-or-pixels) might help

Comment: @choz I know that there are other methods of measurement. Is it just up to the developer to decide which one to use?

Comment: For me, I'd use `%` when I want to split something equally for various kind of viewports, if it can't be totally equal, i'd use media queries and use `px` instead.

Comment: I personally use `%` for element sizes and `em` for fonts after setting a baseline of `14px` on the body. What you do is entirely up to you, just make sure you're consistent and what you use is compatible with all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For responsive design for example, using percents is the way to go, as elements having, say, a `width: 50%;` will always use half the container on any device, whatever the size, as opposed to, say, `width: 400px;` which would be messed up in a small size device.

But of course sometimes you want to use pixels to define an element to always have a fixed width. It really depends on the use case. But the main thing to have in mind is how the element will adjust in different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

## When you can use it

You can use percent sizes whenever the container/parent's corresponding dimension (what the percent is out of) is explicitly set.

One notorious example is setting percent height out of the window. This only works if `html` and `body` height are also set, because these are the parents of all elements. If they are both set, then they both have an explicit height, and therefore any child element can have its height set.

---

### Why you should use it

When "is it okay to use percents" is up to your discretion. Most of the time it is used with dynamic layouts, especially with widths, as @choz mentioned in the comments.