# Flexbox list of 8, have on 2 lines

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox that has a list of 8 items. I want 4 to be on each row. I have tried clear:both and targeting with nth-child but having no luck. Can this be done by targetting the CSS only? I have no control over the HTML so this will be the only way of fixing this issue.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-list {
  padding: 5px 2.5%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>one</h5>
    <p>aa</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>two</h5>
    <p>bb</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>three</h5>
    <p>cc</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list" style="">
    <h5>four</h5>
    <p>dd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>five</h5>
    <p>ee</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>six</h5>
    <p>ff</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>seven</h5>
    <p>gg</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>eight</h5>
    <p>hh</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flex has no wrap as the default behaviour, you need to set that to wrap first. For items per row, just set width to the items. For example if you set width of 24% to each item, it will automagically align 4 per row . https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flex-wrap: wrap` and the `flex-basis` for each item `25%`. And don't forget to set `box-sizing: border-box` for each item.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-list {
  padding: 5px 2.5%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>one</h5>
    <p>aa</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>two</h5>
    <p>bb</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>three</h5>
    <p>cc</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list" style="">
    <h5>four</h5>
    <p>dd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>five</h5>
    <p>ee</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>six</h5>
    <p>ff</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>seven</h5>
    <p>gg</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>eight</h5>
    <p>hh</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I was hoping there was another workaround without using widths too

Comment: You are welcome! I think there is no solution without setting a width.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the HTML code, use `width` and `flex-flow: row wrap` as follow:

```
    .flex-container {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        width: 400px; /* or whatever */
    }

    .flex-list {
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 100px;  /* or whatever */
    }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ouftrspb/1/

Comment: Should you not use % instead of px, so it is more responsive ?

Comment: Perfect thank you, I was hoping there was another workaround without using widths. But this should still do the trick

Comment: Good observation, both can be used, it depends on need. As you suggest, I generally use `%` or `em` metrics, but for the sake of the answer and out of a general context, I prefer using px (also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285058/css-percentages-or-pixels )

Answer (score -1):

General case: you can force creation of a row after the 4th flex item by inserting a **::pseudo 100% wide** right there. Even if the 4 first elements don't fill the 1st row, this ::pseudo will need to occupy a row alone thus elements 5 to 8 will go on another row.
You need to move the first 4 elements before the ::pseudo with a negative `order`.

EDIT: IMHO CSS3 Grid layout is preferable here if you want horizontal alignment between rows.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-list {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 5px 2.5%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.flex-list:nth-child(-n+4) {
  order: -42;
  flex: none;
  width: 7.5%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.flex-container::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>one</h5>
    <p>aa</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>two</h5>
    <p>bb</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>three</h5>
    <p>cc</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list" style="">
    <h5>four</h5>
    <p>dd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>five</h5>
    <p>ee</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>six</h5>
    <p>ff</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>seven</h5>
    <p>gg</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <h5>eight</h5>
    <p>hh</p>
  </div>
</div>
```