# Navbar Link Not Disappearing when its near the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi so I'm creating a navbar menu and what i got is a disaster after changing the size of the web page to phone size.
this what its look like after scalling chrome …
[image]

Also thee Hemberger icon should show me the nav bar below the logo when i click it But its not working too.

I swear I couldn't find any problem to fix so I'm posting this question

My code: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Lagash Scientific Publishing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="menu">
        <div class="red-box">

            <nav class="navbar">

                <!-- logo -->
                <div>
                    <img src="img/logo-Lagash-2.jpg" alt="" class="lagash-logo">
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                </a>

                <div class="navbar-links">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </nav>
        </div>





    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

style.css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.red-box {
    border: 100px solid #90241f;
    background-color: #90241f;
    height: 0.20px;
}

.lagash-logo {
    width: 126px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
    top: 14px;
    left: 114px;
    right: 1px;
}

.navbar  {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
}

.navbar-links ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.navbar-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: block;
}

.toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: .75rem;
    right: 1rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .toggle-button {
        display: flex;
    }

    .navbar-links {
       display: none; 
       width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .navbar-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .navbar-links li {
        text-align: center;
    }


    .navbar-links {
        padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }

    .navbar-links.active {
        display: flex;
    }

}
```

script.js

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have a fixed width for your logo, see:

```
.lagash-logo {
    width: 126px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
    top: 14px;
    left: 114px;
    right: 1px;
}
```

Nothing wrong with that ofcourse, but you have to shrink it down in your media query that you've defined at the bottom of your code, see:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .toggle-button {
        display: flex;
    }

    .navbar-links {
       display: none; 
       width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .navbar-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .navbar-links li {
        text-align: center;
    }


    .navbar-links {
        padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }

    .navbar-links.active {
        display: flex;
    }

}
```

Here you need to put your `.lagash-logo` class selector and define a smaller width.

Also a small note, maybe you should use percentage instead of pixel for your images, see: [CSS - Percentages or Pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285058/css-percentages-or-pixels)

Comment: Ok thanks for the image i fixed the first problem but what about the other problem when i click in the hamburger icon the menu links are not showing please check the code if you can and thank you