# How do I make side row with pictures followed by texts in the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I'm  doing a portfolio project and I'd like to do something similar to this, but it happens that when I'm doing the responsive part, the row pops out of the div. So i would like to know what do I do (or change) to make it decrease alongside the div.

this is what is happening when I shrink the page:[draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1obN.png)

HTML

```
<section class="experience">
<h2 class="subtitle">Experience</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img">
    <p>HTML</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img">
    <p>CSS</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img">
    <p>JavaScript</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item4">
    <img src="img">
    <p>UX/UI Designer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.experience {
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 30px 25px;
  margin: 0px 70px;
  background-color: rgba(4, 7, 30);
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
 }

.subtitle {
  color: #fff;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  place-self: center;
  margin: 30px 0px;
  gap: 300px;
  width: 1100px;
  max-width: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: #0e184b;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 30px 20px 0px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.item img {
  width: 70px;
}

.item p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.item4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 30px 50px 15px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.item4 img {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.item4 p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.row {
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(#5981bc, #0a189a) 0.5;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Everyone will gladly help if you can share what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)
here's an example:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

span {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=1">
    <span>Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=2">
    <span>Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=3">
    <span>Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=4">
    <span>Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=5">
    <span>Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=6">
    <span>Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=7">
    <span>Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=8">
    <span>Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=9">
    <span>Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=20">
    <span>Title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Update:
added another example:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(24, 35, 133, 1) 0%, rgba(80, 117, 184, 1) 100%);
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #061537;
  border: solid 3px transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #f0f0f0;
  border: solid 5px transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

body {
  color: white;
  background: #072854;
}

.experience {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 25px 25px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: rgba(4, 7, 30);
}

.box {
  /* set row's border thickness down here by adjusting padding */
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* set row's width down here */
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 700px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(24, 35, 133, 1) 0%, rgba(80, 117, 184, 1) 100%);
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: #061537;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 80px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.item::after:not(.item:last-child) {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 80%;
  right: -5px;
  width: 3px;
  background: white;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

span {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: 100;
}

hr {
  /* if you wanna add margin to the item's play with second value */
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #dcdee0;
}
```

```html
<section class="experience">
  <h2 class="subtitle">Experience</h2>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?random=6" />
        <span>HTML</span>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?random=5" />
        <span>CSS</span>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?random=4" />
        <span>Javascript</span>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?random=3" />
        <span>HTML</span>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?random=2" />
        <span>CSS</span>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?random=1" />
        <span>Javascript</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: it worked well, thanks! but i grew the column width to fit the entire range and since this all is inside another div when I'm doing the responsive it comes out of the div it is in. is there a way to prevent it by making it decrease along with the div?

Comment: I made this as an example to show you that you can use flexbox to achive what you want. Sorry because I dont have access to your code I can only guess, maybe it comes out because of `width:500px;` in `.row{}`, you should play with it to get the desierd result! If you could edit your question and post your code, I could help you better

Comment: Alright if you remove `gap: 300px;` and change `width: 1100px;` to for example s.th like `width: 90%;` (use  % percentage not px. [why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285058/css-percentages-or-pixels)) it will get ok, I also updated the answer and added another example for you hope it helps, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
.container{display:flex;gap: 0.8rem;width:200px;overflow:auto}
.item{display:flex;flex-direction:column}
.item div{width:48px;height:48px;background-color:#e1e1e1}
.item p{text-align:center}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p>Box 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p>Box 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p>Box 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p>Box 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p>Box 5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```