# Responsiveness in different monitors

Tags: reactjs, react-native, responsive-design, responsive, single-responsibility-principle

I have a React app that I created following a design for 1920X1080. on 27inch / 24inch/ 13inch leptop the app looks great. but if I render the app on a 34 inch wide screen half screen for example, the app does not look very good. what is the best way to create a responsive React app? is media queries good enough ? or maybe I should use MUI or somthing?

I use media queries.

Comment: Take a stab at understanding CSS in general https://youtu.be/h3bTwCqX4ns?si=dXAv5Efz33gTAWK-

Answer (score 0):

I think it strongly depends on the app and your design goals.
"Freezing" your components is a valid option and can enhance readability (Twitter).
I would give [relative measurement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285058/css-percentages-or-pixels) a try, since they scale with the screen.

Comment: 1. ideally the answer should be fact based, opinions should be in comments 2. some questions that are uncleared aren't worth your time until author provided more details

Answer (score -1):

I Think you can use Tailwindcss https://tailwindcss.com/
It's very useful utility-first CSS framework

Comment: If they don't understand responsiveness and CSS in general, slapping another abstraction layer on top is unlikely to help,

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Your assumption dose not make any sense Tailwindcss have very good documentation that can help to achieve what is required 
the answer provided is based on the main question.
Anyway it's your opinion

Comment: There's nothing they can get from the Tailwind documentation they can't get from CSS-Tricks or MDN. It's better to learn CSS so they can stand on their own two feet in any dev environment vs. being dependent on Tailwind. Also check the State of CSS survey for how the popularity of TW is dropping off.